# Facebook page not appearing in developers/apps page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

So I go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps to try to begin to add an app to a page.  The page has 26 fans and I was allowed to create a vanity URL but the page does not appear on the apps page.  Anyone have a reason as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to be there. http://developers.facebook.com/apps lists *apps that you develop*.

Go to the app page, then click "Add to My Page", from there you can add an app to your page.

[image: Add to Page]